# If $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise and $f_n$ is differentiable everywhere, can $f$ be differentiable but with $f'\ne\lim f_n'$?

Tags: real-analysis

There are plenty of examples that $f'$ doesn't exist somewhere, but could $f'$ exist everywhere but not equal to $\lim f_n'$?.

Also what if $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! $f'$ may exists but $\lim f_n' \neq f'$. Here's one example: $$f_n(x)=\frac{x}{1+n^2x^2}\;;\;x\in \Bbb R$$

Here, $f_n \rightrightarrows  f\equiv0$ . But $$f_n'(x)=\frac{1-n^2x^2}{(1+n^2x^2)^2} \longrightarrow \begin{cases} 0&\text{if}\;x \neq 0\\1&\text{if}\;x=0\end{cases} \neq f' \equiv0$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_n(x)=\frac1n\sin(n^2x)$. Then $f_n\to0$ uniformly but $f_n'(0)=n\not\to0$.